# PHP migration issue

Tags: php, laravel, migration, nano

I am deploying a website (second time around). I edited nano .env, but when I try to migrate it comes back with:

```
The environment file is invalid!
Failed to parse dotenv file. Encountered an invalid name at [nano .env].
```

I tried to put NAME_APP in quotation marks and changed name multiple times - no joy.

This is the nano .env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:***********
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=*****
DB_PASSWORD=*****

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=*****
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=****
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I also tried to open the file by nano /var/www/html/.env but that does not seem to show actual file...

What am I missing?

Comment: the `.env` file would be in the root of the project, kinda confused what you are trying to say above or what this has to do with what text editor you are using

Comment: not sure if it's just the way you've written the post, but it looks like your filename is actually `nano .env` -- your filename needs to be something like `prod.env` -- `nano` is a CLI function to edit a file. Also since you can't open it by `nano /var/www/html/.env` I'm guessing that filepath isn't correct.